# Getting internal server errors from nginx on edits

Tags: support

Had these a few times when editing questions and editing answers, and I just got it when looking up a revision history for [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2847677/revisions). Doesn't happen always, but I've got at least 3 of these this morning.

These are the sorts of errors which spits out a page which just says:

> 500 Internal Server Error
>
> ---
>
> nginx

not the lovely picture you sometimes get, along with some text telling you know that a member of the team will look at it shortly.

Comment: I've had two or three "500 Internal Server Error" messages in the last five minutes all from stackoverflow.com, and mostly seeming random -- reload the page a minute or two later and it's fine. Seen it on my Reputation page, and a couple of others.

Comment: dito. same here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>You're getting unlucky and catching us in the middle of a deployment.</s>

(note that we tend to deploy a LOT on weekends, though that tapers off as we get into Monday AM PST)

Simply refresh the page.

Actually, nginx (new part of stack) was running out of resources due to too many connections. We've adjusted it...

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I guess I should expect Stack Overflow to behave similarly to the way I do before I've had my coffee on (UK) Monday mornings. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I just got something like

```
                            Internal Server Error
                                  nginx
```

too

Comment: Excellent (sort of) - not just me!